# NPE on ArrayAdapter.clear()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I get a NPE at the line `if(adapter.getCount() != 0) adapter.clear();` just after I have initialized it. Where I'm wrong in my code? I think that because I had just initialized it, there should not be a NPE, but I'm wrong..
Here I put 3 methods relater to the adapter:

```
    package com.example.app.Fragment;
public class FragmentGestioneCorsa extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = FragmentGestioneCorsa.class.getSimpleName();

private Context context;
private DatabaseLocale db;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private  Spinner spnLinee;
private Button aggiornamento;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    linee = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    context = getActivity();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gestione_corsa, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    spnLinee = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinnerLinee);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spnLinee.setAdapter(adapter);
    spnLinee.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    popolamentoSpinner();

    aggiornamento = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonAggiornamento);
    aggiornamento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Se scrivo DownloadLinee.execute() ottengo l'errore:
            // If I write DownloadLinee.execute() I get the error:
            // Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static contecxt
            DownloadLinee l = new DownloadLinee();
            l.execute();
        }
    });
}

private void popolamentoSpinner(){
    if(adapter.getCount() != 0) adapter.clear();
    db = new DatabaseLocale(context);
    SQLiteDatabase dbLeggibile = db.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] colonne = {DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceLinea(), DatabaseLocale.getTagNomeLinea()};
    String tabella = DatabaseLocale.getTableName();
    Cursor cursore = dbLeggibile.query(tabella, colonne, null, null, null, null, null);
    while(cursore.moveToNext()){
        adapter.add(cursore.getString(0) + " " + cursore.getString(1));
    }
    cursore.close();
    db.close();
}
}
```

Why this NPE?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring twice `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter`, once in the `onViewCreated` method, and once as a member of the class.

When you initialize it in `onViewCreated`, in fact it's initializing a local variable which has no visibility in `popolamentoSpinner`. Basically, it's not the same variable in the 2 functions, so in fact you never initialize the varibale called `adapter` that you use in `popolamentoSpinner`!

One solution would be to remove the declaration in `onViewCreated` so you are sure that you initialize the member variable:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    spnLinee = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinnerLinee);
    adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spnLinee.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The adapter you declare in `onViewCreated()` is a local variable so the field , `private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;`, that you try to access in `popolamentoSpinner()` will still be `null`. In `onViewCreated()` do:

```
spnLinee = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinnerLinee);
adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```